# Где можно найти информацию по работе с GDAL на C#?

Tags: c#, python-3.x

Можно ли сделать на шарпе что-то подобное написанное на питоне? Пока только смог написать начало на шарпе. Где можно найти информацию по работе с GDAL на шарпе?

```
import gdal
import osgeo.gdal as gdal
import numpy as np
import sys
import os

#открытие изображения исопльзуя библиотеку gdal
g=gdal.Open("D:/SV/obr.tif")
#получение первого канала
b=g.GetRasterBand(1)
b1=b.ReadAsArray().astype( np.float32)
#получение проекции
proj=g.GetProjection()
transform=g.GetGeoTransform()

xsize=g.RasterXSize
ysize=g.RasterYSize
```

Comment: ИМХО, кроме "скрина с питоном" было неплохо словами объяснить, что Вы хотите

Comment: , и вместо скриншотов вставить код, который: легко ищется и копируется

Comment: Безусловно, можно, честно говоря, вообще с трудом представляю задачу, которая решается на питоне, но не решается на C#. Однако, как сказали выше, непонятно, что именно Вы хотите сделать. Уточните, какой пакет вы используете для работы с библиотекой, и, естественно, хотя бы примерно, опишите задачу, выложите код в виде текста и вероятность того, что Вам помогут очень сильно возрастет.

Comment: Странно, вроде всё понятно написано.не стал писать код текстом так как на скрине видно что работа с GDAL осуществляется и есть подписи конкретно какие действия выполняются, я спросил можно ли что то подобное делать на шарпе и если да то попросил подсказать источники где это написано, так как сам я не смог найти(не там искал возможно). Всё.

Comment: ваш вопрос (и особенно ответ на него) в дальнейшем будет полезен кому-то ещё, а текст на картинках поисковыми роботами не распознаётся :)

Comment: ещё не смотрели следующие примеры: [простой](http://vector-sol.ru/Blog/16) и сложный -- [исходники SharpMap](https://github.com/SharpMap) ?

Comment: собственно SWIG-обёртка [GDAL/OGR для C#](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp) с [примерами](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps).